# need solution with CSS alignment property

Tags: html, css, web

How do you align radio button and checkbox icons horizontally? i have tried flexbox's justify content center, but the items still go haywire. Please help.

```css
     body {
      color: #faebd7;
      background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #7b4397, #dc2430);
      text-align: center;
      padding: 5%;
     }

     main {
      background: linear-gradient(35deg, #cc2b5e, #753a88);
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: auto;
      margin-left: 15%;
      margin-right: 15%;
      box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
     }

     h1 {
      padding: 1.1em;
      margin: auto;
      font-family: Roboto, monospace;
     }

     p {
      font-family: B612, monospace;
      margin: 10px;
     }

        .form-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
        }

     .form-group {
      font-family: B612, monospace;
      margin-left: 15%;
      margin-right: 15%;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
     }

     .text-white {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Roboto, monospace;
     }

     #dropdown {
      font-family: B612, monospace;
     }

     #number-label {
      font-family: B612, monospace; 
     }

        .btn.btn-primary {
         margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<main class="container">

   <h1 id="title">How's the stream?</h1>

   <p id="description">
    Have you watched Jordon Baade stream over on <a style="color: #fff;" href="https://www.twitch.tv/bpwnd" target="_blank"><strong>Twitch</strong></a>? If you have, I'd like to know what you think so far, and get your opinion on a few other things!
   </p>

   <form action="#" id="survey-form">

    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name" id="name-label">Name:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" required>
        <br><br>
     <label for="email" id="email-label">Email:</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required> 
            <br><br>
     <label for="number" id="number-label">Age:</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" min="13" max="85" id="number" placeholder="Enter your age" required>
     </div>
        <br>
        <label for="dropdown" id="dropdown">Are you enjoying the stream?</label>
         <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" class="form-control">
          <option disabled value="">Select an option</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
         </select>
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-group">
         <fieldset>
          <legend>What's your favourite topic that he stream?</legend>
                <div class="form-container">
                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="programming" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="stream_topic" value="programming">
              <label for="programming" class="form-check-label">Programming</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="gaming" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="stream_topic" value="gaming">           
                 <label for="gaming" class="form-check-label">Gaming</label>
             </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="harmonica_practice" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="stream_topic" value="harmonica_practice">
                 <label for="harmonica_practice" class="form-check-label">Harmonica Practice</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="guitar_practice" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="stream_topic" value="guitar_practice">
              <label for="guitar_practice" class="form-check-label">Guitar Practice</label>
             </div>
                </div>
         </fieldset>
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
         <fieldset>
          <legend>What services do you use to watch live streams?</legend>
          <div class="form-container">
                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="twitch" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="stream_service" value="twitch">
              <label for="twitch" class="form-check-label">Twitch</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="youtube_gaming" type="checkbox" name="stream_service" value="youtube_gaming">
              <label for="youtube_gaming">YouTube Gaming</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="ustream" type="checkbox" name="stream_service" value="ustream">
              <label for="ustream">UStream</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="playstation_now" type="checkbox" name="stream_service" value="playstation_now">
              <label for="playstation_now">Playstation Now</label>
             </div>
             </div>
         </fieldset>
        </div> 
        
        <div class="form-group">
       <label for="comments">Additional comments:</label><br>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Enter your comments" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>

            <br>

         <button type="submit" class="btn.btn-primary" id="submit" rows="3">Submit answers</button>
        </div>

   </form>

    </main>

    <footer class="text-right" container>
     <a href="https://www.jordanbaade.com" target="_blank" class="text-white">Made by Seyienei with help from Jordan Baade.</a>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Do you use bootstrap?

Comment: you want them to be next to each other or on top of each other?

Comment: on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `align-items: flex-start;` with `.form-container`

```css
body {
      color: #faebd7;
      background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #7b4397, #dc2430);
      text-align: center;
      padding: 5%;
     }

     main {
      background: linear-gradient(35deg, #cc2b5e, #753a88);
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: auto;
      margin-left: 15%;
      margin-right: 15%;
      box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
     }

     h1 {
      padding: 1.1em;
      margin: auto;
      font-family: Roboto, monospace;
     }

     p {
      font-family: B612, monospace;
      margin: 10px;
     }

        .form-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: flex-start; // Changed this
        }

     .form-group {
      font-family: B612, monospace;
      margin-left: 15%;
      margin-right: 15%;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
        text-align: left; // Change this
     }

     .text-white {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Roboto, monospace;
     }

     #dropdown {
      font-family: B612, monospace;
     }

     #number-label {
      font-family: B612, monospace; 
     }

        .btn.btn-primary {
         margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<main class="container">

   <h1 id="title">How's the stream?</h1>

   <p id="description">
    Have you watched Jordon Baade stream over on <a style="color: #fff;" href="https://www.twitch.tv/bpwnd" target="_blank"><strong>Twitch</strong></a>? If you have, I'd like to know what you think so far, and get your opinion on a few other things!
   </p>

   <form action="#" id="survey-form">

    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name" id="name-label">Name:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" required>
        <br><br>
     <label for="email" id="email-label">Email:</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required> 
            <br><br>
     <label for="number" id="number-label">Age:</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" min="13" max="85" id="number" placeholder="Enter your age" required>
     </div>
        <br>
        <label for="dropdown" id="dropdown">Are you enjoying the stream?</label>
         <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" class="form-control">
          <option disabled value="">Select an option</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
         </select>
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-group">
         <fieldset>
          <legend>What's your favourite topic that he stream?</legend>
                <div class="form-container">
                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="programming" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="stream_topic" value="programming">
              <label for="programming" class="form-check-label">Programming</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="gaming" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="stream_topic" value="gaming">           
                 <label for="gaming" class="form-check-label">Gaming</label>
             </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="harmonica_practice" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="stream_topic" value="harmonica_practice">
                 <label for="harmonica_practice" class="form-check-label">Harmonica Practice</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="guitar_practice" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="stream_topic" value="guitar_practice">
              <label for="guitar_practice" class="form-check-label">Guitar Practice</label>
             </div>
                </div>
         </fieldset>
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
         <fieldset>
          <legend>What services do you use to watch live streams?</legend>
          <div class="form-container">
                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="twitch" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="stream_service" value="twitch">
              <label for="twitch" class="form-check-label">Twitch</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="youtube_gaming" type="checkbox" name="stream_service" value="youtube_gaming">
              <label for="youtube_gaming">YouTube Gaming</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="ustream" type="checkbox" name="stream_service" value="ustream">
              <label for="ustream">UStream</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
              <input id="playstation_now" type="checkbox" name="stream_service" value="playstation_now">
              <label for="playstation_now">Playstation Now</label>
             </div>
             </div>
         </fieldset>
        </div> 
        
        <div class="form-group">
       <label for="comments">Additional comments:</label><br>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Enter your comments" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>

            <br>

         <button type="submit" class="btn.btn-primary" id="submit" rows="3">Submit answers</button>
        </div>

   </form>

    </main>

    <footer class="text-right" container>
     <a href="https://www.jordanbaade.com" target="_blank" class="text-white">Made by Seyienei with help from Jordan Baade.</a>
    </footer>
```

Comment: thank you. and how do i align the name, email and age, horizontally?

Comment: Add `text-align: left` to `.form-group` Updated my code.

Comment: it aligned to the left with the same amount of space it had before. i have been at this problem for hours now, i'm at my wit's end.

Comment: I think you should open a new question for the new issue.

Comment: it's in here, in the same code. can you kindly help?